# raspbian SSH access refused from windows

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, putty, ssh-keys

I have Raspbian installed on Raspberry 3, I am trying to access it with SSH keys.

I have generated **Public** and **Private** **key**, the `Public_Key` is inside Raspbian's file `~/.ssh/authorize_keys`

The file look like this:

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "000"
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx and more....
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

After that I have set my connection inside **putty** with the `private key`,
but its said **Connection Refused**

I have tried to Ping it(192.168.1.46) and I see the machine is **online**.

So I have thought it is a port problem, so I have actived **ufw** and 
`sudo ufw enable; sudo ufw allow ssh`
and on `ufw status` it's seem that ufw is active and port 22 is open in IPV4 and IPV6.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm changing this answer entirely for simplicitys sake.  i think i jumped ahead.

you have 2 choices:  convert the keypair you create with putty to openssh format, or generate a keypair with openssh and import it into putty.

**Using openssh:**

On the raspberry pi

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "yourname@yourwindowscomputerhostname"
```

choose where to save it (defaults to `~/.ssh/id_rsa`) and choose a passphrase if you prefer. You will now have 2 files.  `id_rsa` is your private key . `id_rsa.pub` is your public key.   copy the contents of your public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

now take the private key and save it on your windows machine and open puttygen

1. Click Conversions from the PuTTY Key Generator menu and select Import key.
2. Navigate to where you just saved the OpenSSH private key and click Open.
3. Under Actions / Save the generated key, select Save private key.

Now you should be able to connect to the raspberry pi, with a functional keypair in a format that the OpenSSH server on the Raspberry Pi expects

Comment: I have insert to `authorized_keys` the new data and still there is no connection.
what do you mean by `user@server`?

Comment: okay, lets say you generated a keypair in open ssh as the user bob on the server  bobscomputer.   the resulting id_rsa.pub (default public key name)  will read like ' ssh_rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAgEAwrr66r8n6B8Y0zMF3dOpXEapIQD9DiYQ6D6/zwor9o

39jSkHNiMMER/GETBbzP83LOcekm02aRjo55ArO7gPPVvCXbrirJu9pkm4AC4BBre5xSLS

7soyzwbigFruM8G63jSXqpHqJ/ooi168sKMC2b0Ncsi+JlTfNYlDXJVLKEeZgZOInQyMmt  bob@bobscomputer'

Comment: i need to add user@ip to the end of the public key after i encode it with ssh-keygen?

Comment: no it should append it when its generated and its not actually important, just formatting.  lets back up.  did you generate the private and public keys with putty or with openssh or some other program?

Comment: all of my steps,
I have created the keys with PuTTygen
save both of them,
I have upload the public key to another server,  and download it with wget to .ssh folder.
then i encode it with your syntax - `ssh-keygen -i -f Public_Key > openssh.pub`

and then transfer it to `authorized_keys` and reboot the server.
I haven't add any bob@bobcomputer, because i didnt know which name to give.
my username on the raspberry machine is `pi` and localip `192.168.1.46`.

this is new key I have just created and put in the server. 
http://halomli.co.il/key

Comment: I have also tried right now to create keys with `ssh-keygen` but when i try to convert it its said `uudecode failed`

Comment: i think i confused you more than helped you, i thought you were further along.  i've changed my answer to be more helpful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75470/discussion-between-itzikb-and-timmy-browne).

Comment: A problem with ssh keys won't cause a "Connection Refused" error.

Answer (score 0):

> Connection Refused

this means that the remote device (the raspberry) refused your attempt to make a TCP connection. There are a few things that could be wrong. The simplest explanation is that there is no process listening for connections on the port that you tried to connect to. In other words:

- The ssh server isn't running on the raspberry.
- The ssh server is running, but it's not listening for connections on the port that you tried to connect to.
- You got the IP address wrong and you're not trying to connect to the correct host.

"Connection refused" can also be caused by a firewall, packet filter, etc. which is interfering with your connection attempts.